# How can I enable Windows authentication for ftp on Windows 7 Pro?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7, ftp, iis-7.5

I have an ftp server running on my desktop pc (windows 7 professional x64):

[image]

However, when I look at the authentication types in IIS Manager I don't see Windows Authentication as an option:

[image]

I've found several guides for setting up authentication through IIS Manager, but nothing about using Windows Auth for FTP.

Is it possible to use windows authentication to connect to an FTP server in this manner? If so, how can I set it up?

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes? I don't post much here but I think I've clearly explained my problem, and I haven't found any duplicates on here, or any other resource which explains how I can configure this properly.

Comment: because FTP doesn't support Windows Auth (it wasn't my downvote).  Are you asking if you can authenticate against windows accounts?  or have it login automatically from another machine using the currently logged in user on a domain?

Comment: @MikeAWood "FTP doesn't support Windows Auth" is all I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't DV but I'm guessing it's because you are running it on your desktop PC and they figure it is OT and belongs on Superuser.

Regardless, Integrated Windows Authentication isn't available in FTP in IIS.

You could consider running a 3rd party "FTP" server like WingFTP that supports domain authentication.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I didn't think it would be off topic. I wasn't sure between the two and guessed here because I figured IIS related questions would be more suitable here. You answered my question at any rate, thanks.